# Wordpress using AJAX to Pass JS Variables to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to pass AJAX JS Variable to PHP in WordPress to access the variable.

I want to use it on the Woocommerce thank-you page

Here is the main plugin file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_custom_function' );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_myaction', 'so_wp_ajax_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', 'so_wp_ajax_function' );


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so_enqueue_scripts' );
function so_enqueue_scripts(){
  wp_register_script( 
    'ajaxHandle', 
    plugins_url('ajax.js', __FILE__), 
    array(), 
    false, 
    true 
  );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxHandle' );
  wp_localize_script( 
    'ajaxHandle', 
    'ajax_object', 
    array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) 
  );
}
```

My second PHP file: my_custom_function.php

```
function so_wp_ajax_function(){
  //DO whatever you want with data posted
  //To send back a response you have to echo the result!
  echo $_POST['name'];
  echo $_POST['age'];
  wp_die(); // ajax call must die to avoid trailing 0 in your response
}

function my_custom_function(){

// how can I pass it here
}
```

I am able to echo the $_POST['name'] but it is in the console log

JS File: ajax.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    alert('asd');
  //Some event will trigger the ajax call, you can push whatever data to the server, simply passing it to the "data" object in ajax call
  $.ajax({
    url: ajax_object.ajaxurl, // this is the object instantiated in wp_localize_script function
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
      action: 'my_custom_function.php', // this is the function in your functions.php that will be triggered
      name: 'John',
      age: '38'
    },
    success: function( data ){
      //Do something with the result from server
      console.log( data );
    }
  });
});
```

I want to pass the value to my_custom_function(), any ideas? tried many ways but can't seem to work

Comment: Let me see if I got it: you are running the function with ajax to send the name and age to the function my_custom_function (), right? What happens when you try to retrieve the values ​​with $ _POST in this function?

Comment: So you wish to pass the variable value in JavaScript?

Comment: @TomLima Nothing is displayed out, meaning cant read the post value

Comment: @AShah I am trying to pass the JS Value to PHP

Comment: What is the value contained in the "ajax_object.ajaxurl" variable ? When you open your devTools in the Network tab, can you see any calls being made correctly for this function?

Comment: @TomLima mysiteurl.com/plugin_path/ajax.js?ver=5.5.3 

Not sure why it is a get request, tried to use _GET and nothing shows up as well

Comment: Your second PHP file is called admin-ajax.php, right?

Comment: @TomLima No that is the WordPress admin-ajax.php file, it is used to handle ajax requests.

Comment: Can't you also access $_POST variables in "my_custom_function" if you are calling it via ajax?

Comment: @JamesHamann Cant, $POST in my_custom_function gives nothing..

Comment: Hmm, well it seems like there is a problem with the setup then, just in terms of how to accomplish what you want. Maybe you do not need to call this separate function to accomplish it, if you are using admin-ajax already. Can you walk through exactly what you want to do again in greater detail?

Comment: `my_custom_function.php` isn't the correct action.  It should be (and you should change this) `my_action`... ...also you're getting the $_POST[''] data in an entirely different function from `my_custom_function()`, so why are you expecting it there.